# Update table to make primary key out of two foreign keys

Tags: sql, database

Have a table `sample_tag` which already exists with 1000's of entries.

It consists of two foreign keys, `sample_id` and `tag_id`.

However, the database is allowing duplicate `sample_id/tag_id` records to be created.

Without creating a new table, is there a SQL statement to update the `sample_tag` table such that the two foreign keys, together, function as its primary key?

Database is MySQL using phpMyAdmin

Comment: Which database are you using? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL,...?

Comment: make a unique constraint of both columns, the syntax is different depending on rdms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main challenge is how you resolve the duplicates. If there are already duplicate keys, then you'll need to address these as a separate step (either deleting the duplicate, or merging any other columns as you see fit).

To check for duplicates, try:

```
SELECT sample_id, tag_id, COUNT( * )
FROM sample_tag
GROUP BY sample_id, tag_id;
```

If there are none, then you can go ahead and delete any existing primary key, and create a new one.

Comment: Thankfully,  the problem was noticed before many duplicates were added.  They have been manually removed.  No duplicates remain

Comment: You should then be able to run an ALTER TABLE and add your new primary key (having first removed an existing one etc).

Comment: Cool beans: my pleasure!